# Sum of $n$ terms of the series: $30+144+420+960+1890+3360+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-by-parts

I need to find the general term and the sum of $n$ terms of the series:$$30+144+420+960+1890+3360+\cdots$$
The answer provided my book is: $$U_n=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+4),\quad S_n=\frac{1}{20}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(4n+21).$$ 
And I've no idea how to move on. It doesn't look like an arithmetic progression or a geometric progression. As far as I can tell it's not telescoping. What do I do? Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guessing a degree 4 polynomial from 6 terms may be considered a bit bold.  As if every sequence starting with two identical terms were constant ...

Comment: What Hagen von Eitzen said. The next terms could be anything

Comment: The question is meaningless unless you are given the general term. There are an infinity of functions so that the first 6 integer values satisfy what's given in the summation, each giving different sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Assuming that the general term is $U_n=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+4)$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
U_n&=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+n(n+1)(n+2)=24\binom{n+3}{4}+6\binom{n+2}{3}.
\end{align}$$
Then recall the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity):
$$\sum_{n=k}^N\binom{n}{k}=\binom{N+1}{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robert Z Sir.Your explanation taught me something new

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $U(n)=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+4)=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+n(n+1)(n+2)$

If $V(n)=n(n+1)\cdots(n+k),$

Now, $\underbrace{r(r+1)\cdots(r+k)(r+k+1)}-\underbrace{(r+1)\cdots(r+k)(r+k+1)(r+k+2)}$

$=(r+1)\cdots(r+k)(r+k+1)[r-(r+k+2)]$

$$\implies(k+2)\cdot V(r+1)=T(r)-T(r-1)$$ which is Telescoping with $T(m)=m(m+1)\cdots(m+k)(m+k+1)$

Put $r+1=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$

Comment: Thank you for you explanation @lab bhattacharjee Sir.